# How do I make jQuery File Upload play nicely with Backbone and Rails?

Tags: jquery, file-upload, backbone.js

I'm trying to use the [jQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) plugin to preview my images before I send them from Backbone to Rails. When I submit, I need to send in a bunch of other data from the form at the same time.

Before I added the image, I was submitting the form and doing this:

```
this.collection.create(formData);
```

The URL that I want to send the data to is defined in the collection. Using File Upload, should I redefine the URL in the plugin and use the formData option to send the rest of the data from the form? Is there a better way to do this with Backbone?

Comment: I separated my file/photo upload from my user profile model so the upload, preview, crop, data relay happens on a separate route than my profile route. My profile model has an attribute called imageSRC which is only manipulated server side whenever someone changes, edits, deletes their photo. It works cleanly for me and made sense rather than trying to tangle it together. So to answer part of your question, I defined the URL in the plugin and work outside models and collections for the file upload. Server then takes the finished image and saves the imageSRC as a model attribute.

Comment: To follow up with this, I was able to send the additional form data using the formData option provided with File Upload. The kind of hacky thing is that File Upload will only make the API call if there is a photo attached to the form. If the user decides not to upload a photo, I had to create an API call separate from the File Upload call with this.collection.create()

Comment: Yeah. I didn't quite like how the optional formData stuff was implemented in File Upload. Maybe there is a way to do it better within its constraints but I ended up scrapping it in favor of the separate route. Maybe the optional formData is really only for data associated directly with the file upload. E.g. cropping coordinates for the photo so when you upload, server can immediately modify the file.